# Isomorphism between matrix algebra and the opposite of the algebra formed by modules homomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

I know that this exercise is easy, but I have problem to solve it:

Let $A$ be an algebra (associative and unital) and $X$ a free 
 $A$-module generated by $\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$. If $C$ is the algebra whose elements  are  modules homomorphisms from $X$ to $X$, prove that $C^{o}$ (the algebra opposite to $C$) is isomorphic (as algebra) to $M_n(A)$.

My attempt was to define $F$ such that $F(f)=\big(f(x_1)|f(x_2)|\cdots|f(x_n)\big)\in{M_n(A)}$ for every $f\in{C^o}$. Then $F(f\cdot{}g)=F(g\circ{}f)=F(g)F(f)$, the contrary  what I need.

Could someone help me?

Comment: It seems to me that this is false, unless I am missing something. You have $M_n(A)\simeq C$ and not $C^o$, and in general it is not true that $C\simeq C^o$.

Comment: Note that $F(f)$ as written is not an element of $M_n(A)$, unless we have $X = A^n$.

Comment: It might help to take a closer look at your definition of a free module

Comment: Why not? . It was for me the natural form to define a map between $C^o$ and $M_n(A)$

Comment: If you want $f(x_1)$ to be the column of a matrix, then $f(x_1)$ needs to be a column-vector in $A^n$.

Comment: Oh yes, you are rigth.

Comment: But, by dfinition of free module,  we also have that $X$ is isomorphic to $A^n$,

Comment: If you define 
$$
F(f) = \pmatrix{f(x_1)^T\\ \vdots \\ \ f(x_n)^T}
$$
then you end up with the opposite isomorphism you want, since $A \mapsto A^T$ is an isomorphism between $M_n$ and $M_n^{op}$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we are taking left $A$-modules, and writing homomorphisms on the left, then there is a ring isomorphism $\mathrm{End}_A(A^n)\cong\mathbb M_n(A^{\mathrm{op}})$. Note that the opposite is on the entries of the matrix. This sends an endomorphism $f$ to the matrix $F=(f_{ij})$ such that $f(x_j)=\sum_if_{ij}x_i$.

To check the multiplication, suppose $g\mapsto G=(g_{ij})$. Then
$$ gf(x_j) = \sum_{i,k}f_{kj}g_{ik}x_i $$
so $gf$ corresponds to the matrix $g\cdot f$ provided we take the matrix multiplication in $\mathbb M_n(A^{\mathrm{op}})$.

We can now use the transpose to obtain a ring isomorphism
$$ \mathbb M_n(A^{\mathrm{op}}) \cong \mathbb M_n(A)^{\mathrm{op}}, \quad M\mapsto M^t. $$

In general, we have a matrix decomposition for direct sums, so that
$$ \mathrm{End}_A(X\oplus Y) \cong \begin{pmatrix}\mathrm{Hom}_A(X,X)&\mathrm{Hom}_A(Y,X)\\\mathrm{Hom}_A(X,Y)&\mathrm{Hom}_A(Y,Y)\end{pmatrix}. $$
In your question we have $X\cong A^n$ and $\mathrm{End}_A(A)\cong A^{\mathrm{op}}$ via $f\mapsto f(1)$.